# What is rails asset_sync gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have started with RoR and S3 and I am not clear with assets.

There is a asset_sync gem

https://github.com/AssetSync/asset_sync

Could someone clarify what does it mean

> for synchronises Assets between Rails and S3

Also I see that heroku doesn't recommend use it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/please-do-not-use-asset-sync
Heroku recommends using a a CDN instead of asset_sync.

1. Is CDN used now instead asset_sync?
2. Can I not use asset_sync at all? Or I must use it in web-app?
3. What is the best practice for compile assets?

Thank you!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn#adding-cloudfront-to-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Amazon Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html), not S3. S3 is for storing files and is not very good or fast at serving static assets.

Cloudfront serves assets from super speedy servers spread across the globe by caching. You don't need to upload the assets.

What you do is setup a distribution on Cloudfront such as:

```
https://mycdn.cloudfront.net
```

You then setup your distribution to use your heroku app as the origin server.

So on the first request for:

```
http://mycdn.cloudfront.net/some_asset.png
```

Cloudfront will forward the request to:

```
http://myapp.heroku.com/some_asset.png
```

And caches the response so any subsequent requests will go to those super speedy edge-cache locations.

At one point cloudfront only allowed a S3 bucket as the origin server which is no longer the case. `asset_sync` is a relic from that time.

There is no point in uploading assets to S3 today. Even less in using asset_sync wich will not play nice with heroku's super smooth asset pipeline integration.